# Elegant way to unfold RDD[LablePoint] to DataFrame something like RowMatrix

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have libsvm with (lable, sparse Vector) which I can load to RDD[LablePoint]. I am wondering if there is an elegant way to convert to a dataframe that holds unfolded something like RowMatrix in scala.